# After zip64Mode is set to "always" in Ant build, it says Error: Could not find or load main class when i run java program

Tags: java, jar, ant

I got

```
build Error creating jar archive contains more than 65535 entries.
```

So i added

```
zip64Mode = "always"
```

Now the build is successful, but when i try to run the java program, i get

```
Error: Could not find or load main class.
```

I am not able to access any class in the jar.

Below is my build file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="create_run_jar" name="Create Runnable Jar for the 
Project *****" basedir=".">
<!--this file was created by Eclipse Runnable JAR Export Wizard -->
<!--ANT 1.7 is required -->
<!-- Replace the eclipse directory value here -->
<property name="ECLIPSE_HOME" value="" />
<presetdef name="javac">
    <javac includeantruntime="false" />
</presetdef>
<import file="build.xml" />

<target name="prepare-lib">
    <delete dir="${basedir}/dist" />
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/dist" />
    <copy todir="${basedir}/dist" flatten="true">
        <path refid="*****.classpath" />
    </copy>
</target>


<target name="create_run_jar" depends="cleanall,build,prepare-lib">
    <jar destfile="${basedir}/*****.jar" 
filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain" zip64Mode="always">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" 
value="*****" />
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="." />
        </manifest>
        <fileset dir="../*****/classes" />
        <fileset dir="../*****/bin" />
        <fileset dir="../*****/bin" />
        <fileset dir="../*****/bin" />
        <fileset dir="../*****/bin" />
        <fileset dir="../*****/bin" />
        <zipgroupfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" 
dir="../xtwitter/dist" />
    </jar>
</target>
</project>
```

This is my imported file build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<project basedir="." default="build" name="*****">
<property environment="env" />
<property name="*****" value="*****" />
<!***Other Properties*****!>
<property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars" />
<property name="target" value="1.8" />
<property name="source" value="1.8" />

<path id="****.classpath">
  <!**all dependencies **!>
</path>
    <target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="classes" />
    <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="classes">
        <fileset dir="src">
            <exclude name="**/*.java" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="classes" />
</target>
<target depends="clean" name="cleanall">
    <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${*****.location}" 
inheritAll="false" target="clean" />
    <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${*****.location}" 
inheritAll="false" target="clean" />
    <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${*****.location}" 
inheritAll="false" target="clean" />
    <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${*****.location}" 
inheritAll="false" target="clean" />
    <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${*****.location}" 
inheritAll="false" target="clean" />

</target>
<target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build" />
<target name="build-subprojects">
    <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${*****.location}" 
inheritAll="false" target="build-project">
        <propertyset>
            <propertyref name="build.compiler" />
        </propertyset>
    </ant>
    <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${*****.location}" 
inheritAll="false" target="build-project">
        <propertyset>
            <propertyref name="build.compiler" />
        </propertyset>
    </ant>
    <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${*****.location}" 
inheritAll="false" target="build-project">
        <propertyset>
            <propertyref name="build.compiler" />
        </propertyset>
    </ant>
    <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${*****.location}" 
inheritAll="false" target="build-project">
        <propertyset>
            <propertyref name="build.compiler" />
        </propertyset>
    </ant>
    <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${*****.location}" 
inheritAll="false" target="build-project">
        <propertyset>
            <propertyref name="build.compiler" />
        </propertyset>
    </ant>
</target>
<target depends="init" name="build-project">
    <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}" />
    <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="classes" 
source="${source}" target="${target}">
        <src path="src" />
        <classpath refid="*****.classpath" />
    </javac>
</target>
<target description="Build all projects which reference this 
project. Useful to propagate changes." name="build-refprojects" />
<target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib 
directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
    <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" 
includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar" />
    </copy>
    <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
        <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar" />
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" 
includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar" />
    </unzip>
</target>
<target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" 
name="build-eclipse-compiler">
    <property name="build.compiler" 
value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter" />
    <antcall target="build" />
</target>
</project>
```

Comment: wow, what type of project has more than 65535 entries?  Why not split into multiple jars?

Comment: I could assume Splitting to multiple jars will be an alternative to not use zipMode64. But do you have any idea as why am i getting this error when zipMode64 is set to "always" @ScaryWombat